# Is it possible to query the result of a query?

Tags: categories, query

I'm not sure if the is even possible, and couldn't find an answer, so I figured I'd ask on here.

Basically I want to know if it is possible to query a query result?

What I want to do is query for all posts from a specific category, and then run a query on that result for separate multiple categories.

I know how to query these separately, but do not know how, or even if its possible to query the result of a query?

Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Since you can instantiate to a variable a query you can do it as much times as you want. Of course query loops require a lot of connections to the database so you have to be careful. Very often if you need many subqueries it basically means that your workflow can be enhanced in some way.

Example of a subquery:

```
$some_posts = new WP_Query();
$some_posts->query('cat=1&showposts=2');

while ($some_posts->have_posts()) : $some_posts->the_post();

    // Start new subquery with query values
    $inner_query = new WP_Query();
    $inner_query->query('cat=1&showposts=2');

    while ($inner_query->have_posts()) : $inner_query->the_post();

        // Do something in your inner/sub query

    endwhile;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot, and let you know my outcome.

There is a reason, and you may be right that my workflow/logic may be off.

I've listed another question here that states my actual problem, and case:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193675/how-to-query-all-posts-of-a-specific-category-and-any-other-category-combinatio

Comment: I've tried the sub query idea from above, but It doesn't seem to work. If possible I need the first query to pull all id=7 category posts, and then the second query to pull all say id=8 category posts from the resulting id=7 posts pulled from the first query.